# Continuity of convex functions that have continuous restrictions to closed subspaces

Tags: continuity, convex-analysis

Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional normed vector space , let $U\subset X$ be an infinite-dimensional closed subspace, and let $f:X\to[0,\infty)$ be convex.

**Question:** If the restriction $f|_U$ is known to be continuous, does then $f$ have to be continuous as well?

In finite-dimensional vector spaces $f$ must be continuous, no matter what $f|_U$ does (and if $U$ is finite-dimensional, every convex $f$ has a continuous restriction, see a comment below). I also know that under certain conditions $f|_U$ can be extended to a continuous convex function $\tilde f:X\to\mathbb R$ (Hahn-Banach-like results, see the book of Borwein and Vanderwerff, for instance). But $f$ and $\tilde f$ don't have to coincide. And I know that continuity is equivalent to continuity at only one point (even more: equivalent to boundedness from above in a neighbourhood of only one point), but I couldn't show either one of these assumptions in my case.

I expect that the answer is negative (just a feeling) but I could not came up with a counter example.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: any finite dimensional subspace is closed and the restriction is continuous...

Comment: ah I see, so if $U$ is finite dimensional, then any convex function (no matter whether it is continuous) satisfies my assumptions. Ok. I have to add that $U$ is infinite dimensional as well. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it will ever work. Let $g:E\to [0, \infty)$ be convex but not continuous. Then, $f: E^2 \to [0, \infty)$ defined by $f(x,y) = g(x)$ satisfies your assumptions

Comment: Yeah you are right. This is a nice counterexample. Write it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in general not valid.

Assume that $E$ is a (infinite) normed space admitting a non continuous convex function $g:E\to [0,\infty)$.
Then, the function $f:E^2 \to [0,\infty)$ defined by $f(x,y) = g(x)$ is convex.
Further, $f$ is constant and thus continuous on the closed subspace $U = \{0 \} \times E$. However, $f$ is not continuous on $E^2$.